# Can ClickOnce deployment be used with windows mobile and compact frameworks?

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Can I use the ClickOnce deployment method to deploy and auto update applications targeted for the windows mobile platform (eg smartphone or pocket pc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

True Click-Once is not supported.  You might look at these articles to give you a better feel for what can be done:

- [MSDN Article on Deployment Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446503.aspx)
- [Alex Feinman's article on self-updating apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446487.aspx)

You can also package the app into a [CAB File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx) that you put on the web for OTA deployment.  There are also a couple third-party providers like [CloudSync](https://cloudsync.com) and [mProdigy](http://www.b2m-solutions.com) (used neither so YMMV) for OTA as well.

Answer (score 1):

No. Hopefully in the future.